# xamarin android LocalBroadcastManager does not exist in current context

Tags: xamarin, dll, xamarin.android

After I added senbird.dll && sedbird.unity.dll && websocket-sharp.dll to my project compiler start to showing error:

> LocalBroadcastManager does not exist in current context.

It has also happened before when I installed some nuget package. (I dont remember the name of the package. I deleted it afterwards).

It shows error just with LocalBroadcastManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll to my project.